# Grails Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'

Tags: java, grails3

I'm new to Grails and developing with Java. I'm having an issue where I have Java 8 set up as my JAVA_HOME environment variable but Grails is not recognizing it. How do I configure Grails to use Java 8?

Stack Trace:

```
Error Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.jvm.UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.assertUsingVersion(UnsupportedJavaRuntimeException.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.checkJavaVersion(ConnectorServices.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ConnectorServices.close(ConnectorServices.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultGradleConnector.close(DefaultGradleConnector.java:57)
    at org.grails.cli.gradle.cache.CachedGradleOperation.call(CachedGradleOperation.groovy:78)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.populateContextLoader(GrailsCli.groovy:526)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeProfile(GrailsCli.groovy:509)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.initializeApplication(GrailsCli.groovy:307)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:270)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:159)
| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not determine java version from '10.0.2'.
```

Comment: What's the result of running `java -version`?

Comment: java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

I thought I changed it.

Comment: You probably need a newer version of Groovy/Grails that supports the new way the version string is formatted in java since 9.  I had to upgrade Gradle to 4.8 to have it correctly identify JDK 10.0.2

Comment: I have: 
Grails Version: 3.3.8
Groovy Version: 2.4.15
and Gradle 4.10
Installed

Comment: Update:
For some reason java -version was giving me different results depending on where in the file system I ran it. Java 10 in my root folder and Java 8 in my project folder. I reset JAVA_HOME in the project folder to Java/Home and I was able to start Grails with Java 8. 

What version of Java should I use with Grails 3?